# How to minimize my css files using webpack

Tags: sass, webpack

i'm using webpack and would like to minimize css file. At this time it is 2.25MB. I found this optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin plugin but it din't help and my css file is same size. Here is my settings

```
'use strict';    
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const webpackCommon = require('./webpack-common.config');
var OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = merge(webpackCommon, {
   devtool: 'none',
   plugins: [
      new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
      new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin(),
      new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
         /\.js$/,
         beautify: false,
         comments: false,
         compress: {
            unused: true,
            dead_code: true,
            warnings: false,
            screw_ie8: true
         }
      }),
      new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
         'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
         '__DEV__': false
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
         minChunks: 2,
         maxChunks: 15,
         minChunkSize: 10000,
         name: 'vendor'
      }),
      new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
         assetNameRegExp: /\.scss$/g,
         cssProcessor: require('cssnano'),
         cssProcessorOptions: { discardComments: { removeAll: true } },
         canPrint: true
      })
   ]
});
```

this is prod config and it requires common config file. Here it is

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
   entry: {
      main: './src/main.js',
   },
   output: {
      filename: '[name].js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../PashaGraph/WebClient/public')
   },
   watch: true,
   watchOptions: {
      aggregateTimeout: 100
   },
   plugins: [
      new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].css")
   ],
   module: {
      loaders: [
         {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel'
         },
         {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap!sass?sourceMap')
         },
         {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css-loader?minimize!sourceMap')
         },
         {
            test: /\.woff2?$|\.ttf$|\.eot$|\.svg$|\.png|\.jpe?g|\.gif$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'url-loader'
         }
      ]
   },
   resolve: {
      extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
   }
};
```

as u see i use sass in my app. Maybe this is a reason why it doesn't reduce size.

Solved! actually i have fonts and they were converted and embedded into css file. Thats why it was such big event with compression (2.25mb). 
By the way i found this solution to restrict maximal size for embedding

```
{
            test: /\.woff2?$|\.ttf$|\.eot$|\.svg$|\.png|\.jpe?g|\.gif$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: "url-loader?limit=60&name=fonts/[name]_[hash].[ext]"
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run the webpack with -p option. It will build for production with very high compression.

> webpack -p

Also, you may need to set the Node_Environment to production else the final build will give some warning message in the browser's console.

Comment: Thanks for solution. I have also found my own solution and update question with it

Answer (score 1):

You can also minify css classnames - that can give up to 40% in bundle size reduction. 
https://github.com/vreshch/optimize-css-classnames-plugin

Comment: nice solution! Ths

Comment: how this plugin works with classes from js libs if related css placed inside index.html?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use source maps in production code. Remove `!sourceMap`.

Comment: thanks, i did it but my bundle.css file still is same size